# A piece of Python code to compute a frequency table of a list of values

Tags: python

I have written a Python 2.5.4 function which accepts as input a list of numbers alongwith the desired number of classes and yields a frequency distribution (i.e. a histogram) of the same data.

While setting class boundaries, I've attempted to increase the accuracy (i.e. number of digits after the decimal point).

Here's my code:

```
def num_after_point(x):
    s = str(x)
    if '.' not in s:
        return 0
    return len(s) - s.index('.') - 1

def histogram(list, numBuckets):
    count = [0] * len(list)
    for i in range(len(list)):
        count[i] = num_after_point(list[i])
    lowest = min(list) - 10**(-max(count)-1)
    highest = max(list) + 10**(-max(count) -1)
    print "Lowest data value:", lowest
    print "Highest data value:", highest
    dataRange = highest - lowest
    bucketSize = dataRange / numBuckets
    print "Bucket Size:", bucketSize
    bucketCountList = [0] * numBuckets
    low = lowest
    high = lowest + bucketSize
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if low < list[i] < high:
            bucketCountList[index] += 1
    print "From", low, "to", high, ":", bucketCountList[index]
    while high < highest:
        low = high
        high = low + bucketSize
        index = index + 1
        for i in range(len(list)):
            if low < list[i] < high:
                bucketCountList[index] += 1
        print "From", low, "to", high, ":", bucketCountList[index]

histogram( [ 0.1, 0.22, 0.333, 0.4444, 0.55555, 0.666666,   
             0.7777777, 0.88888888, 0.999999999, 1.0], 3)
```

Is this code error-free enough?

If not, where and how does it break down?

How can I improve its functionality and efficiency?

Comment: Dear lord why are you on Python 2.5.4

Comment: @Dannnno actually I have started learning Python using the MIT OpnCourseWare course, which was taught in 2011 and uses Python 2.5.4.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [2.5.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.6/), a security fix to 2.5.4.
Alternately either 2.7 or, preferably, 3 would be a better upgrade.
They may be unfeasible, but you should upgrade, [you're 7 years behind](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/)!

---

First things first, don't do hacky stuff that give incorrect bounds.

> lowest = min(list) - 10**(-max(count)-1)

The correct bounds are not the ones you are using!
They are:

```
[0.1, 0.4)
[0.4, 0.7)
[0.7, 1.0]
```

All bar the last 1 inclusive is easy, just remove that hack you are using.
If we put the bound creator in a function then we can create the bounds and re-use them in a future function.
To handle the 1 inclusive you can change it to a 2, (1 + 1).

I would also use comprehensions, they are quite simple, but extremely useful.
For example creating `count` would be:

```
count = [num_after_point(list[i]) for i in range(len(list))]
```

This can be improved by not indexing `list` and not using `len` and `range`.

```
count = [num_after_point(i) for i in list]
```

As most of your function is creating the bounds I'll go through it first.
You want to keep most of your code the same. But:

1. Remove `num_after_point`, `count` and all that mess.
2. Remove all the `bucketCountList` stuff.
3. Change the while loop to a for loop `for _ in range(numBuckets - 1):`.
   Yes you want the -1.
4. After changing `low` and `high`, `yield` them. (`yield low, high`).
5. After the for loop `yield high, highest + 1`, this is the only edge case we will be using.

This should get you:

```
def bounds(list_, numBuckets):
    lowest = min(list_)
    highest = max(list_)
    bucket_size = (highest - lowest) / numBuckets
    upper_bound = lowest
    for _ in range(numBuckets - 1):
        lower_bound, upper_bound = upper_bound, upper_bound + bucket_size
        yield lower_bound, upper_bound
    yield upper_bound, highest + 1
```

Now to use it is *very easy*:

1. You want to go through all the lower and upper bounds of the bounds function.
   simply `for l, u in bounds(...):`.
2. Generate the sum in the bounds.
3. Display everything.

To get:

```
def histogram(list_, num_buckets):
    for lower_bound, upper_bound in bounds(list_, num_buckets):
        data = sum(lower_bound <= i < upper_bound for i in list_)
        print "From", lower_bound, "to", upper_bound, ":", data
```

The only down-side is the one hack we used to include the upper bound.
This has a small impact on the display, but ultimately it's a much nicer solution.

- The bounds are easier to read.
- You can use every number in the range. You couldn't use `0.0999999999` for example.

Finally, not knowing the numbers in the range is a bit... odd.
You should probably allow that, which is using a comprehensions `if`.

```
def histogram(list_, num_buckets):
    for lower_bound, upper_bound in bounds(list_, num_buckets):
        data = [i for i in list_ if lower_bound <= i < upper_bound]
        print "From", lower_bound, "to", upper_bound, ":", len(data)
        print data
```

Comment: what is "list_"? What does the '_ signify?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud `list_` is the same as (in your code) `list`, the only difference is with `list_` you can still use the built-in `list` function. `_` signifies not overwriting something, but you can't think of a good synonym. I.e. `array` or `data`.